# How to set up an rsync backup to Ubuntu securely?

Tags: ssh, backup, security, rsync

I have been following various other tutorials and blog posts on setting up a Ubuntu machine as a backup "server" (I'll call it a server, but it's just running Ubuntu desktop) that I push new files to with rsync.  Right now, I am able to connect to the server from my laptop using rsync and ssh with an RSA key that I created and no password prompt when my laptop is connected to my home router that the server is also connected to.  I would like to be able to send files from my laptop when I am away from home.  Some of the tutorials I have looked at had some brief suggestions about security, but they didn't focus on them.

What do I need to do to let my laptop with send files to the server without making it too easy for someone else to hack into the server?

Here is what I have done so far:

- Ran ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id to create a key pair for my laptop and server.
- Created a script on the server to write its public ip address to a file, encrypt the file, and upload to an ftp server I have access to (I know I could sign up for a free dynamic DNS account for this part, but since I have the ftp account and don't really need to make the ip publicly accessible I thought this might be better).

Here are the things I have seen suggested:

- Port forwarding: I know I need to assign the server a fixed ip address on the router and then tell the router to forward a port or ports to it.  Should I just use port 22 or choose a random port and use that?
- Turn on the firewall (ufw).  Will this do anything, or will my router already block everything except the port I want?
- Run fail2ban.

Are all of those things worth doing?  Should I do anything else?  Could I set up the server to allow connections with the RSA key only (and not with a password), or will fail2ban provide enough protection against malicious connection attempts?  Is it possible to limit the kinds of connections the server allows (e.g. only ssh)?

I hope this isn't too many questions.  I am pretty new to Ubuntu (but use the shell and bash scripts on OSX).  I don't need to have the absolute most secure set up.  I'd like something that is reasonably secure without being so complicated that it could easily break in a way that would be hard for me to fix.

Comment: I'll answer in longer form in a moment, but for now I'll just say disable password login in sshd_config - it means only people with a public key on the server (IE you) can connect and password login isn't possible. If you do this you shouldn't need fail2ban

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think your trying to over architect a bit. SSH is one of the most secure file transfer protocols and if your already rsyncing over ssh then your 90% there.  Your router is acting as a basic firewall so you shouldn't need to turn on iptables for a personal backup server.

Stick with port 22. It will make life much easier.

fail2ban is a nice script for public servers, specially where password based logins are enabled. On your server it's going  to make more problems then it will fix. I wouldn't recommend running it. Here are my suggestions:

- Go ahead and get the dynamic IP, it will make it easier, and about the time you go traveling, your ftp script will fail for some really strange reason.  Basically KISS.
- Disable Password logins for ssh. In /etc/sshd_config change `PasswordAuthentication yes` to `PasswordAuthentication no`, and make sure `challengeresponse` is set to  `no`. That will bock any one without your private key from logging in at all.

Other then that your pretty much covered by default. ssh encrypts traffic and verifies the host/client. There not a lot left after that.

Comment: Also change `challengeresponse` to `no`, so that PubKey is the only possible authentication method

Comment: Thanks, guys!  I will follow your suggestions.  @coteyr -- a couple clarifications on typos: you mean "Your router is acting as a basic **firewall**"  and "It will **block** any one **without** your private key from logging in at all" right?

Comment: Yes, corrected. Added in "challengeresponse no" as well.